# ibn Mas'ud & the Jama'ah

Tags: hadith, source-identification

This [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/269866/the-hadeeth-about-following-the-majority-refers-to-the-early-muslims) mentions the following report from ibn Mas'ud RA :

> “The majority of the people have left the Jamaa‘ah. Surely, the Jamaa‘ah is that which concurs with the obedience of Allaah."

Can someone find me the exact source(s)?

Comment: i think it's https://al-maktaba.org/book/9200/193 or https://al-maktaba.org/book/3722/11552#p4 or https://al-maktaba.org/book/13162/280#p1

Comment: Jazak Allahu Khayran